# How do i set default permission classes to my custom permission (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, api-key

I created a custom permission to allow users only with a specific API KEY to access my API endpoints..

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from django.conf import settings

class CustomerAccessPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        is_allowed = request.META.get('HTTP_X_APIKEY') == settings.API_KEY
        return is_allowed
```

How do i apply this to my REST_FRAMEWORK configurations in settings.py as a default PERMISSION_CLASS
OR is there a better way for me doing this.. (NOTE: i have already handled authentication, i don't want authenticated users to access my end points)

Comment: can't you set `"PERMISSION_CLASS":"path.to.CustomerAccessPermission"` ?

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work, or is there is a specific syntax for me to write it.. this is how i wrote mine `REST_FRAMEWORK = {
....
    "PERMISSION_CLASS": "utils.permissions.CustomerAccessPermission",

}`

Comment: that how it should be. BTW, be more specific about *"that didn't work"*

Comment: even with this i could still access by API endpoints without specifying the X-Apikey in my headers

Comment: have checked whether the `has_permission()` method is getting called or not?

Comment: I have solved the problem.. the syntax was `REST_FRAMEWORK = {
....
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": (
        "utils.permissions.CustomerAccessPermission",
    )
}`